# Wygwam Images Alternative Text mandatory field

Tags: wygwam

Has anyone found a way of making the alternative text field in the Wygwam images dialogue box mandatory.I have a large number of users and its something they always forget to do when adding images.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open this file: `THEMES_FOLDER/third_party/wygwam/lib/ckeditor/plugins/image/dialogs/image.js`

Look for `id:"txtAlt",` and replace it with `id:"txtAlt",validate:CKEDITOR.dialog.validate.notEmpty("ALT text required"),`

That should work...

Comment: Note: Be aware, that this should be redone every time you update wygwam.

Comment: Sweet ,that works a treat . Thanks very much